# htaccess mod rewrite rule appending url params

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a gallery script that works very simply.

The index page (php) loads all pictures in thumbnail view based on the url params. I'm trying to use the rewrite rules to mask the urls so they look nicer, but I'm having an issue.

The index page takes `a=gallery&name={name of gallery}`

The rewrite is working to the extent that it's rewriting the urls to `/gallery/{name of gallery}`

The problem is I'm getting `/gallery/{name of gallery}/?a=gallery&name={name of gallery}` which is obviously not desired and redundant anyway.

Here's my rule, I've been messing with this and I'm tired to going over the docs and just want this finished.

```
# enables rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

# we always direct requests to the www subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# some url rewriting
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ ?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/$ ?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?a=$1&name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/$ ?a=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Edit: added complete htaccess file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way and see how it works for you.

```
    # enables rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine on

    # we always direct requests to the www subdomain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gallery 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?url=$1&name=$2 [PT,L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gallery 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: This appears to work, however I'm getting a directory listing for the rewrite url instead of the script. Maybe there is something else going on here?

Comment: a directory listing for the url? Are the directories real? meaning is /gallery/ a real directory?

Comment: Yes, they are real directories.

Comment: So do you have an index file inside of the directory or are you trying to use the index in the root? And where is the htaccess file?

Comment: /index.php does all the work and is the only index file. (there are no other php scripts in /gallery/ or any sub-directories in /gallery/

Comment: Just curious do you actually have any type of files in there?

Comment: /gallery/ has directories (the names of galleries) and each of those has image files... all jpg.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47582/discussion-between-panama-jack-and-jeff)